# Specific Example of a Morphism of Schemes for which the Push-Pull Morphism is not an Isomorphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, derived-algebraic-geometry

Consider a Cartesian diagram of schemes as follows:

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X \times_Z Y @>{\tilde{\pi}}>> Y\\
@VV{\tilde{\phi}}V @VV{\phi}V\\
X @>{\pi}>> Z
\end{CD}$

From the isomorphism $\phi_*\tilde{\pi}_*\cong \pi_*\tilde{\phi}_*$, for any quasicoherent sheaf $F \in QCoh(Y)$, one obtains by adjunction the push-pull map $\pi^*\phi_{*}(F) \to \tilde{\phi}_*\tilde{\pi}^*(F)$. There are many sources which claim that this map is not an isomorphism, thus motivating the need for derived algebraic geometry (for example, the fourth page in [this section](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/GL/HA.pdf) of Gaitsgory-Rozenblyum). However, is there a specific example where $\phi$ *is quasicompact* and this morphism fails to be an isomorphism?

I have read through the example where $Y$ is the countable disjoint union of points and $X = \mathbb{A}^1$, but because pushforward doesn't send quasicoherent sheaves to quasicoherent sheaves in this case, this doesn't seem (to me) to be one of the problems that derived algebraic geometry fixes.

Comment: Let $Z$ be $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ for $n\geq 2$. Let $Y$ be the open complement of the origin.  Let $X$ be the closed inclusion of the origin.  Let $F$ be the structure sheaf.

Comment: Oh of course. This makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Are you silently turning $F$ into a sheaf on $X \times_Z Y$ in the sentence  just after the diagram?

Comment: Yes thank you! I've edited my question for clarity.